# cp and mv using wildcards and forgetting to specify a destination directory

Tags: shell, wildcards, cp, mv

It has happened to me several times that I used `cp` or `mv` with wildcards but I forgot to specify a destination directory. Here is an example of the mistake when collecting logs:

```
~# mkdir problem_logs
~# cd problem_logs
~/problem_logs# cp -pv /var/log/messages*
'/var/log/messages' -> '/var/log/messages.1'
```

You can see that I forgot to write the `.` destination directory and because `/var/log/messages*` expanded exactly to two file names the second one was overwritten by the first one.

```
~# echo cp -pv /var/log/messages*
cp -pv /var/log/messages /var/log/messages.1
```

**What are good measures to prevent such disasters?**

- Of course **not using the `root` account** is a good measure (but it will prevent only some mistakes). Unfortunately there are multiple (commercial) linux-based platforms where many basic operations require `root` privileges and users have UID 0 there by default. The platforms often require non-standard modifications to be able to use non-root users and `sudo`.
- Learn to use the option **`-i`** (`--interactive`) which requires confirming every overwrite.
- Learn to use the GNU **`-n`** (`--no-clobber`) option which prevents all overwrites.
- Learn to use the GNU syntax specifying the destination directory using the option **`-t`** (`--target-directory`). Example: `cp -pvt. /var/log/messages*` I  can see that I can still forget to write the `.`

The last two options have a disadvantage that they are not standardized in POSIX. They are GNU extensions.

- **What are other possibilities to be considered?** (including e.g. alternative shell)
- **What are their advantages and disadvantages?** (including possibilities already listed)

This question is certainly not asking for personal opinions. It is asking for possibilities and their relevant objective properties.

Comment: The `-i` option only prompts if you want to overwrite a file -- not "confirm every operation" as you've stated it.

Comment: This seems to be asking about people's opinions about working safely with the command line. As such, the question can never have a definite answer.

Comment: @Alex You are right! I am not used to use `-i`. Maybe I will learn to use it. I fixed my mistake in the question.

Comment: If you want to always use `cp -i` or `cp -n` you can define an alias, e.g. `alias cp='cp -i'` in your `.bashrc` or whatever is appropriate for your shell.

Comment: There are pros and cons to using `-i` with `rm`, `cp` and `mv` in an alias, but mostly cons. People will point out that changing the perceived default behaviour of these tools will make you forget that you rely on `-i` even on systems where the alias is not in effect. It's better to make a habit of actually reading the command line before pressing `Enter`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I do not understand why do you see this question as opinion based. Certainly this is a question which does not have a simple single answer as most of the real-life questions but the answers are not opinion-based. Every measure to prevent the mistake has certain advantages and disadvantages. Everyone can evaluate them herself/himself.

Comment: @Bodo This with description of advantages and disadvantages could certainly be an answer.

Comment: Well, it is my _opinion_ that one should read the commands that one types, not that one should default to using `-i`. Others will come along and say "always use `set -e` and/or `set -u` in your script or in your shell" and then someone else says "no, don't do that" (I know that's not what the question is about, but still, it the typical thing someone would "contribute" with). In the end, it comes down to personal preference, and to opinions about how to work with the shell.  This is the _definition_ of an "opinion-based" question, it has no objective answer.

Comment: You have here already four options, each which their downsides, most of which you already seem to know (you can make mistakes in commands as root or non-root, `-i` can be annoying in some cases, `-n` doesn't work when you actually want to overwrite something, `-t` doesn't work in non-GNU systems and relying on an alias to be set everywhere can be a disaster if you use a system without it). Picking one's poison based on such facts seems based on personal preference to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only flat<sup>[1]</sup> answer (IMhO) is to create a shell function.

Something like:

```
cy() { cp -i "$@"; }
```

Using a new name (**`cy`**<sup>[2]</sup>) will ensure that if the solution has not been installed in some system, nothing will be executed. And, the solution could work on any system. It even could test if some version of an utility exists in the system before using it, or just raise an error/warning.

Then, all/any of the solutions that you listed could be used.

<sup>[1]</sup> not making a pre-judgement (or just giving opinions) about possible solutions or source (GNU).
<sup>[2]</sup> select a name `cy`, `co` (FWIW, [`co` is the RCS checkout command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/co)) or some other that makes sense to you as user and has the least probability of collision in the systems where it is going to be used.