# I lost files by using the "mv" command and I don't know where they are!

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mv

I lost some files by using the `mv` command. I don't know where they are.  They are not in the directory to which I intended to copy them.

Below is a transcript of what I did:

```
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main$ cd
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  GameShell  Music  Pictures  pratice  Public  Templates  Videos
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~$ mkdir tp2
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  GameShell  Music  Pictures  pratice  Public  Templates  tp2  Videos
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~$ cd Downloads/221-tp2-public-main/
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main$ ls
backup  copybash  Dockerfile               ntfy-1.16.0  packets.txt     README.md      restore        secret
cloud   data      Dockerfile_CAYS07019906  ntfy.zip     rapport-tp2.md  remplacer.sed  sauvegarde.sh  tail
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main$ mv rapport-tp2.md tp2
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main$ mv Dockerfile_CAYS07019906 tp2
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main$ mv packets.txt tp2
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main$ mv sauvegarde.sh tp2
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main$ cd
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~$ cd tp2/
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/tp2$ ls
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/tp2$ ls -l
total 0
samuelcayo@CAYS07019906:~/tp2$ cd ..
```

Comment: IOW, you should have done `mv rapport-tp2.md $HOME/tp2` (or equivalently `mv rapport-tp2.md ~/tp2`) and similarly for the rest, since you created the directory `tp2` inside your home directory.

Comment: The only file you can "restore" is `sauvegarde.sh` which is now `~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main/tp2`

Comment: Is it wrong to be slightly amused that the one file you *didn't* lose is the one called "sauvegarde"?

Comment: Related question about unintentional overwrites when using wildcards: [cp and mv using wildcards and forgetting to specify a destination directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/557827/19702)

Comment: Note how you typed `tp2/` when doing cd, where forcing its status to a directory is unimportant, but typed `tp2` when doing mv, where it is important.

Comment: Just for the record, this is exactly what source control can help you with.  Just restore from the history.  You may want to learn `git`.

Answer (score 82):

You created a directory called `tp2` in your home directory, i.e. you created the directory `~/tp2`.  You then changed into `~/Downloads/221-tp2-public-main` and started to move files with `mv`.

Since you specified the target of each `mv` operation as `tp2`, and since `tp2` was not a directory in your current directory,  each file you moved was instead *renamed* `tp2`.  You overwrote the file previously called `tp2` each subsequent time you ran `mv`.  In the end, the `tp2` that you were left with is the file previously called `sauvegarde.sh`.

You would have avoided the loss of data by using `~/tp2/` as the target of each `mv` operation.

The `~` refers to your home directory, where you created your `tp2` directory.  The `/` at the end of the target path is not strictly necessary, but it makes `mv` fail gracefully if `~/tp2` is not a directory.

As for what you can do now to restore your lost files; consider restoring them from a recent backup if you don't have other copies of them lying around elsewhere.

Comment: I moved the off-topic discussion on the merits (or lack thereof) of making aliases to the `-i` versions of standard tools [to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135806/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-i-lost-files-by-using-the-mv-command-and-i).

Comment: Note (if it's not already obvious) that making `tp2/` the target of `mv` would *also* have avoided data loss precisely because it makes `mv` fail. Either get the directory right, or put `/` on the end, or both. Since you can't be sure you'll always get the directory right, but you can decide to always put `/` on the end, you should decide to always put `/` on the end.

Comment: Also a good habit could be to use the tab-completion. When you notice that the target was not completed to `tp2/` you notice that something is wrong - the target directory does not exist.

Comment: Some people also like to create an alias from `mv` to `mv -i` so they can't accidentally overwrite a file with `mv`.

Answer (score 28):

The GNU implementation of the `mv` command (the one found on Ubuntu) has an explicit `mv -t myDir` option that checks that `myDir` is specifically an existing directory. This avoids the ambiguity between `mv Source Dest` (*move to*) and `mv Source Directory` (*move into*).

It also fixes the args order in constructs like `find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 mv -t Dir --`, where xargs by default appends args (so that placing the target directory last is not possible). Both these cases would have avoided your issue.

The `mv -i` option also offers protection against overwriting files accidentally.

Comment: And also make a habit out of a) using tab completion and b) using trailing slash in destination arguments

Comment: @Stéphane  Thanks for the edit. I came to GNU relatively recently, after too long on Solaris.

Comment: That is why it is a good idea to use alias on mv, cp so that they are really mv -i, cp -i etc to avoid accidents like this.

Comment: @stackoverblown  I take the opposite view. I spent 15 years on customer sites working for a mainframe manufacturer, and then 30+ years as a contractor. Having basic commands configured to suit the personal prejudices of some cowboy SysAdmin is my idea of hell.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant reminds me of one server I used where every text editor was linked to the sysadmin's (weird) personal favorite editor.

Comment: Why the hostility against alias mv='mv -i' ?  OP appears to be an end-user, not a sysadmin (cowboy or other), so an alias isn't going to mess up scripts or settings that are shared with others.  It's good for average users to have some protection against accidents.

Comment: @AlexanderHanysz  When I am troubleshooting at a client with 100s of workstations, I need them **all** to work as standard. See my previous comment (with upvotes), and the chat referred to by @terdon. One example: make your alias, get used to having it, and then sudo so you can get extra permissions to `mv` some files. Just when you need it *most*, your "safer" alias does not exist in that environment !

Comment: @Paul_Pedant But then one could have set alias sudo='sudo '. Voila! I understand your point of view how aliases make life difficult for you. But without them, users and cowboy admins could too easily get into trouble like the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid doing this, interactively:

```
mv file1 dest
mv file2 dest
mv file3 dest
```

At least, avoid issuing multiple commands like this without checking the result of the first one:

```
mv file1 dest
ls -l dest # is there a dest, containing file1?
```

Instead, combine them into one:

```
mv file1 file2 file3 ... dest
```

If there are two or more files, then `dest` is interpreted as necessarily having to be a directory which exists. If it doesn't exist or isn't a directory, then `mv` fails:

```
mv: target 'dfsafsdfdf' is not a directory
```

If you issue multiple commands without checking their results, you may lose the benefit of whatever few safeguards they provide.

`mv` has a POSIX_standard `-i` option to avoid clobbering a destination which exists. You can include that in your interactive `mv` command via making an alias:

```
alias mv='mv -i'
```

Comment: You should probably explain that the alias is dangerous, because it encourages a dependency on it, making errors more likely when it's not available (e.g. in a `sudo` shell).