# How to display a prompt and prevent execution against basic but dangerous commands like mv or rm

Tags: shell-script, shell, rm, prompt, mv

## Objective

Whenever I use `mv` (or commands of similar nature) I want my shell to prompt me something like "**Hey, you used mv. Sorry but do it again using mv -i**".
I'd like to know the reasonable method to accomplish such interaction.

The purpose is to have my computer complain whenever I use `mv` so I must re-enter `mv -i`. This way I will develop muscle memory to enter `mv -i`.

Having my computer convert my `mv` to `mv -i` under the hood is **not** the purpose, and completely defeats the intention.

If this sounds like a stupid idea in the first place I'd like to know why and better solutions.

## Background

In the past I have used `mv` and mistakenly overwrote files. While [this comment recommends to alias `mv` in a way it actually works as `mv -i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700151/i-lost-files-by-using-the-mv-command-and-i-dont-know-where-they-are#comment1324184_700167), I agree with [this comment about consequences of such customization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700151/i-lost-files-by-using-the-mv-command-and-i-dont-know-where-they-are#comment1324299_700167). Instead of getting used to typing `mv`, I'd rather make it a habit to type `mv -i` so I won't mess up on other machines.

## Concerns

I'm worried about such modifications affecting other scripts or programs which invokes `mv`. Is there a clever way to abort and show prompt only when `mv` is executed by myself through typing and pressing Enter?

## Notes

- I take backup of files, not that it's relevant
- I know I can paste post-its on my desk or posters on my wall to raise awareness
- Environment: Debian, XFCE, xfce4-terminal, Bash

Comment: Aliases are (thankfully) not expanded in scripts by default.

Comment: @Kusalananda, aliases *are* expanded in scripts by default in most shells (including in `csh` where the feature comes from and where they belong as other shells have functions). `bash` is an exception but only when not in posix mode. However, if you define those aliases in the configuration file for the interactive mode of your shell, it will only affect interactive invocations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, my comment was in the light of the user mentioning `bash` specifically.

Comment: As a noob I was expecting solutions for Bash which is the only shell I know, but it's also very helpful to receive such comments for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [@glennJackman's approach](/a/702436) with a wrapper that checks if the first arguments starts with `-` and contains `i` is likely good enough in most common cases, there are a few cases where it fails:

- It gets in the way of `mv --help` (not `--version` which contains `-i`).
- It fails to detect the `-i` in `mv -v -i a b` (or `mv a b -i` which GNU `mv` allows when there's no `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment).
- It doesn't cover GNU's `mv --interactive` / `mv --in` / `mv --i`...
- It misses the missing `-i` in `mv --no-target-dir a b` or `mv -Tdir file`...

For a wrapper to cover all those cases, we'd need it to parse its options the same way `mv` does. Not two implementations parse their options the same way. You'll even find differences between versions of the same `mv` implementations.

The GNU implementation of `mv` (and most utilities) will use `getopt_long()` to parse their options.

If your wrapper could call `getopt_long()` with the same arguments, we'd be sorted. Which leaves two problem:

1. We need to find an interface to `getopt_long()` in the shell
2. we need to figure out those arguments `mv` passes to `getopt_long()`

If you're on a GNU/Linux system, there are possible ways.

While there's no shell CLI to `getopt_long()` in the GNU toolchest, there is one in `util-linux`: its `getopt` utility when used with `-o` and `-l`.

On GNU/Linux, GNU utilities will invoke the `getopt_long()` function from the libc as it will be the GNU libc, so you could use `ltrace` which traces library calls to see what `getopt_long()` call `mv` makes to parse options.

```
$ ltrace -e getopt_long mv -:
mv->getopt_long(2, 0x7ffcf7febd68, "bfint:uvS:TZ", 0x5650dd02fb20, nilmv: invalid option -- ':'
)                           = 63
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
+++ exited (status 1) +++
```

(where `-:` is guaranteed to be a bogus option)

Not good enough as we only see the short options. It's however possible to configure `ltrace` to decode the `long_options` argument there and even to hide the parameters we don't care about.

As a proof of concept, here's a zsh script that would output the `sh`-compatible code for a wrapper function that checks that the `-i` / `--interactive` (or `--help` / `--version`) or their abbreviations before calling `mv`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
die() {
  print -ru2 -- "$@"
  exit 1
}

for cmd do
  getopt_long_call=$(
    ltrace -F/dev/fd/3 3<<'EOF' -o/dev/fd/4 4>&1 > /dev/null 2>&1 -s 999 -A999 -e getopt_long "$cmd" -:
int getopt_long(hide(int),hide(addr),string,array(struct(string,int,hide(int*),hide(int)),zero),hide(int*));
EOF
  )
  getopt_long_call=${getopt_long_call%%$'\n'*}

  [[ $getopt_long_call = (#b)[^\"]#'getopt_long("'([^\"]#)'", [ '(*)' ]) = '<-> ]] ||
    die "Can't determine what getopt_long call $cmd does"

  short_opts=() long_opts=()
  : ${match[1]//(#m)?:#/${short_opts[1+$#short_opts]::=$MATCH}}
  : ${match[2]//(#b)'{ "'([^\"]#)'", '(<->)' }'/${long_opts[1+$#long_opts]::=$match[1]${(l($match[2])(:))}}}
  opts_with_args=(-${(M)^short_opts:#*:} --${(M)^long_opts:#*:})
  opts_with_args=(${opts_with_args%%:#})

  print -r -- $cmd'() {
  (
    opt=$(getopt -qo '${(j[]qq)short_opts}' '${(qq)long_opts/#/-l}' -- "$@") || exit 0
    eval "set -- $opt"
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
      case $1 in
        (-i | --interactive | --version | --help) exit;;
        (--) printf >&2 "%s\n" "Please run '$cmd' with -i/--interactive"
             exit 1;;
        ('${(j[ | ])${(qq)opts_with_args}}') shift;;
      esac
      shift
    done
    echo >&2 "Oops. Something when wrong"
    exit 1
  ) || return
  command '$cmd' "$@"
}'
done
```

For instance, on my system, `that-script mv rm` outputs:

```
mv() {
  (
    opt=$(getopt -qo 'bfint:uvS:TZ' '-lbackup::' '-lcontext' '-lforce' '-linteractive' '-lno-clobber' '-lno-target-directory' '-lstrip-trailing-slashes' '-lsuffix:' '-ltarget-directory:' '-lupdate' '-lverbose' '-lhelp' '-lversion' -- "$@") || exit 0
    eval "set -- $opt"
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
      case $1 in
    (-i | --interactive | --version | --help) exit;;
    (--) printf >&2 "%s\n" "Please run mv with -i/--interactive"
         exit 1;;
    ('-t' | '-S' | '--backup' | '--suffix' | '--target-directory') shift;;
      esac
      shift
    done
    echo >&2 "Oops. Something when wrong"
    exit 1
  ) || return
  command mv "$@"
}
rm() {
  (
    opt=$(getopt -qo 'dfirvIR' '-lforce' '-linteractive::' '-lone-file-system' '-lno-preserve-root' '-lpreserve-root::' '-l-presume-input-tty' '-lrecursive' '-ldir' '-lverbose' '-lhelp' '-lversion' -- "$@") || exit 0
    eval "set -- $opt"
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
      case $1 in
    (-i | --interactive | --version | --help) exit;;
    (--) printf >&2 "%s\n" "Please run rm with -i/--interactive"
         exit 1;;
    ('--interactive' | '--preserve-root') shift;;
      esac
      shift
    done
    echo >&2 "Oops. Something when wrong"
    exit 1
  ) || return
  command rm "$@"
}
```

You'd do:

```
eval "$(that-script mv rm)"
```

In your shell's interactive mode configuration (`~/.zshrc`, `~/.bashrc`...).

To define those wrapper. And then:

```
$ rm a -i
rm: remove regular file 'a'? n
$ rm a --int
rm: remove regular file 'a'? n
$ mv --version
mv (GNU coreutils) 8.32
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Parker, David MacKenzie, and Jim Meyering.
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 rm a -i
Please run rm with -i/--interactive
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a wrapper function: you can add this to your .bashrc (untested)

```bsh
mv () {
    case $1 in
        -*i*) # ok, used `mv -i ...`: invoke the mv command, passing all args
            command mv "$@"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "hey, use 'mv -i'" >&2
            false
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: This will be fooled by something like `mv -v -i ...` but `mv -vi ...` should be OK

Comment: It would be fooled the other way round with GNU-style `mv -t/var/lib -- *` or `mv --no-target-directory a b`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Should not be `return` before `false`? Maybe I have not yet seen this syntax...

Comment: @VlastimilBurián, `false` is to set the exit status to failure. You can also do `return 1`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm booted in Win, so I could not look at my scripts, sorry about that. True, it should be `return 1` by my writing, so writing `false` is equivalent to that? Very well, thank you!

Comment: @VlastimilBurián, `return 1` would be more like `false; return`. `false` exits with a failure status (in practice that's going to be `1`, though you don't need to know about that), and since it's the last command run in that `case` construct, that will be also be the exit status of that construct. And since that `case` construct is the last command run in that `{ ...; }` command group that makes up the body of the function, that will also be the exit status of that `{...;}` command, and of the function when executed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create an alias.

```
alias mv="mv -i"
```

More complicated, but more customizable, would be to create an `mv` shell script, put it into the `/bin`, and the real `mv` move to `/sbin` or any other 'secret' directory. The replacement script will do warnings and call the original `mv` by full path.

If you want to completely save yourself from `mv` - rename or delete the tool.

Yes, other scripts could fail due to such modifications. In this case you can go into those scripts and fix them, by replacing `mv` with a `/secret/path/mv`

Another way - create a special user for everyday life. Create for him (usually in `$HOME/bin`) a copy of real `/bin` with exclusion of dangerous tools. Set a PATH for that everyday-user which will use `/home/everyday/bin` instead of `/bin`.
If some application will now require "dangerous" tools - that application is not for the "everyday" user - switch to a user with more privileges.